# Randomly choosing a word from a text file in C

Tags: c, file, text

I'm quite new at programming and I'm trying to code [Hangman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_%28game%29). I have 10 words saved in a textfile in the same folder as the code and I want the program to randomly choose a word and save that word into a character array.

I've googled and looked around but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Do I use something like `fopen()` and `rand()`?

Comment: I would suggest trying something out (`fopen` and `rand` will almost certainly form part of that solution), and then post a *specific* question when you get stuck.

Comment: You might like to get yourself a C primer.

Comment: I'm not very good so I have really no clue how to even start. If you could give me some kind of push towards the right way it would be helpful

Comment: I doubt you googled, at least you did not read the results. The 1st 10 results for "read text file in C" seem to provide enough to start with.

Comment: The big view I can tell is, you must know how to open a file, how to store your words in an array, and how to choose randomly an element of this array.

Comment: @alk I did read and stuff. However when you're quite new to programming it's not the easiest. 
I know hot to open the file (sorta) and randomly chose an element of this array but no clue how to save the words in an array

Comment: If you tried something, you might like show it (the code) here, telling us why you did it this way and not the other, what you expect to do it, and what you feel does not not work but probably should.

Comment: fgets and fscanf functions are your friends, do some research

Answer (score 2):

assuming the words are written one per line , here's a small piece of code that'll do that :

```
FILE* fp = NULL;
char words[20];
int i = 0 , ran = 0;
srand(time(NULL));
fp = fopen("path" , "r+");
for(; fgets(words , sizeof(words) , fp) ; i++)
          ;
ran = rand() % i;
rewind(fp);
for(i = 0 ; i < ran ; i++)
    fgets(words , sizeof(words) , fp);

 printf("%s\n" , words);
```

beware of not having a new line character at the end of you file because it will be considered as a word and will sometimes be returned to you

Comment: Thanks man! I'm not very good at programming quite yet so I was wondering if you could explain how your code works? :)

Comment: first it goes through the file using `fgets()` when fgets returns `NULL` (this means we reached the end of the file) we then create a random number within the range of the number of words available , after that we go trough the file again looking for that random line/word

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how these words are saved in a file. My first thought is to choose random number and then read a word which is written in a line that has chosen number. But your words have to be written one per line.

Comment: Currently I have the words saved in a textfile as:

Apple
Pear
Orange
etcetc

with enter signs inbetween words.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in three steps:

1. Read all words from file to `char words[N][100]` (here N=10). In C, you can do this as follows:

   ```
   char words[10][100];
   int i = 0;
   while(10>i && fgets( words[i++], 100, file) );
   ```
2. Generate a random number `i` within `[0,N-1]`.

   ```
   int i = rand() % 10;
   ```
3. Return `words[i][]`.

Comment: I can do step2 and 3 but no clue how to read all the words. How do you do it so it recogonizes where a new word starts?

Comment: It depends on how the works are stored in the file. For example, if all words are split by space, you can use `stringstream >>` N times to get all words.

Comment: stringstream >> seems to be a C++ function. Anything in C that you know of?

Comment: Question is C, not C++.

Comment: @user2955782 Easy to use C style code. Use `FILE * pFile` instead to first read all words to `char` array and then use `space` to split the words.

Comment: @djechlin Now in C, updated.

Comment: @user2955782 Now in C, see updated.

Comment: This is not in C (what is `string`?).

Comment: @djechlin Sorry for mixing C with C++. Fixed now.

Comment: @user2955782 Fixed now.

Comment: Better do: `while(10>i && fgets( word[i++], 100, file) );`

Comment: @alk Thanks. Updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm not very good at programming quite yet so I was wondering if you could explain how your code works? :)

Comment: @user2955782 Sure. The idea is to read from file 10 times, each time get a word (max 100 length) using `fgets()` and store it into `words[i][]`.